# How to delete all add-ons from the terminal window?

Tags: raspbian

I downloaded a legiontv add-on and now my Raspberry Pi keeps on freezing after that kodibuild. I therefore either want to delete this add-on, or all add-ons and start afresh. I have kodi 17.6 rasbian strech. Cannot get to system or programs as it freezes. Can I do or format from terminal?

Comment: If you used a package manager to install this feature it may be best to use the same package manager to remove this feature.  If you downloaded and installed a feature manually you are likely going to have to figure this out by your self.  For a list of all packages no matter what their state type: "sudo dpkg -l"

Comment: How did you install kodi? Did you use [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/kodi/), or `sudo apt-get install kodi` ?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start fresh unless there is a compelling reason not to. Clean and fresh is always more reliable than patched up and made over. That said, there are two approaches to consider:

1. The ultimate clean and fresh is to re-install the OS of your choice on either a new SD card, or overwrite the one you have if there's nothing worth saving. You may want to use NOOBS if you want the ease and convenience of installation-via-GUI. You can [read all the details on installing and using NOOBS here.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md)
2. If you [installed kodi using `aptitude` following (for example) the information here](https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_on_Raspberry_Pi), then you can also use `aptitude` to uninstall as follows:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove kodi -y 
sudo apt-get purge kodi`

I have no idea what `legiontv` is, or how it relates to raspberry pi. If you installed it using `aptitude`, you can `remove` it following the steps above. Otherwise you'll need to edit your question to provide some details on this thing.

And finally, FWIW, you should familiarize yourself with the available documentation. For example, [documentation for using `aptitude` will get you started,](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/apt.md) and you can ask questions here about points that aren't clear.